# How to pass Json data from url in stencil prop DateTimeSlot Picker?

Tags: javascript, json

This is https://jsbin.com/rukubifana/edit?html,console,output DateTimeSlotPicker
I want to use

```
var slots = [];
$.getJSON( "/schedule/slots/free/1/30/", function( json ) {
  $.each(json, function (key, val) {
    slots.push(val);
  });
  datetimeSlotPicker.slots = slots
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more information, please? For instance, do you have console errors?

The suggested code should work, in theory.

Also, I would move the declaration of `slots` into the `getJSON` callback. This leads to better encapsulation. On top of that, it's better to use `const` here, since the reference will never change during execution.

You could go even further and drop jQuery, just use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

```js
async function requestSlots() {
  const json = await fetch(request).then((response) => response.json());

  const slots = Object.values(json);

  datetimeSlotPicker.slots = slots;
}
```